# How to optimize this query for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I am learning query optimization by using some structures such as index, index cluster, hash cluster. I have a table Customer and Booking. There are 2 queries that I need to optimize

Query 1:

```
 SELECT BOOKING.BID, CUSTOMER.CID, BOOKING.SEAT_PRICE
    FROM BOOKING, CUSTOMER
    WHERE BOOKING.CID= CUSTOMER.CID
    AND BOOKING.SEAT_PRICE>200;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT BOOKING.BID, CUSTOMER.CID
FROM BOOKING, CUSTOMER
WHERE BOOKING.CID= CUSTOMER.CID
AND CUSTOMER.CID>1900;
```

Theoretically, in order to improve performance, we need to  index/ index cluster/ hash cluster all predicate in WHERE, JOIN, ORDER BY... clauses . However when I try to follow that rule for above queries, it does not have any performance improvements.

For example, for the first query, I create index on both CID columns of BOOKING and CUSTOMER tables. I also create index on column SEAT_PRICE of BOOKING table. The scripts I run as follow:

```
CREATE INDEX BOOKING_SEAT_PRICE ON BOOKING(SEAT_PRICE);
CREATE INDEX BOOKING_CID ON BOOKING(CID);
CREATE INDEX CUSTOMER_CID ON CUSTOMER(CID);
```

Please note that I create trace file to see statistic of query. I run the query to create a trace file before making these indexes. After making these indexes, I run it again to create another trace file. However, the new trace file does not show any improvement in time, CPU, elapsed time, query...etc. It even has worst performance.

Can anyone help me with this please? It really make me frustrated as I do not understand why, I follow exact the rule. I did google but to no avail.

Comment: Have to check execution plans to be sure, but for the first one, only the indexes on seat price and customer.cid are likely to be used. Second one would probably ude both cid ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use composite index:

```
SELECT BOOKING.BID, CUSTOMER.CID, BOOKING.SEAT_PRICE
FROM BOOKING 
JOIN CUSTOMER  -- explicit JOIN
  ON BOOKING.CID = CUSTOMER.CID
WHERE BOOKING.SEAT_PRICE>200;
```

And

```
CREATE INDEX BOOKING_SEAT_PRICE_CID ON BOOKING(SEAT_PRICE, CID);
CREATE INDEX CUSTOMER_CID ON CUSTOMER(CID);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda, composite index work the same as before. Probably I need to learn to read trace file and explain plan. Would you mind to help me with my new question regarding tracefile ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817309/how-to-understand-statistics-of-trace-file-in-oracle-such-as-cpu-elapsed-time